# adding a textbox to photoshop background using dreamweaver

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I am trying to make a website for a friend. I used photoshop to make a website layout and used the slice tool to make buttons. I need to add textboxs to the layout so people can enter than email address / info and submit it to my friends email. When i try to insert textboxs using dreamweaver it puts the box on the bottom on the page not on my layout. I tried dragging and dropping on my layout but nothing. Anyone know how I can get a textbox on my layout?

Comment: sounds like you have a lot of issues. YOu need to post all of your code.

Comment: relying on Dreamweaver's drag and drop WSYWIG editor tools is ... um ... lets say "inefficient". Its a decent enough html/css editor, but you have to know html/css to use it. Check out the code view, and post what doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the design editor instead of the code editor you will need to insert the form first. this should create a red dotted outline in the area you are working in. Then you should be able to insert your text area into that.

Goto Forms tab and click the far left button with the dashed outline
Then insert form fields such as text area etc..